# WRobotPeer native source code

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Where can I find the native source code for the [sun.awt.windows.WRobotPeer](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Platform/windows/sun/awt/windows/WRobotPeer.java.htm) class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`awt_Robot.cpp`](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#av_p04Hv9fs/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Robot.cpp&q=file%3aawt_Robot.cpp&l=337) at Google Code Search.

Comment: ... ha ha and the first thing I see is deprecated Windows API Calls. Thanks a lot!